# validating single set of fields on click using Jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Ive made a form that has several sections, later sections are hidden but will be displayed after a user clicks a next button on current section. Im trying to do simple "must be filled" validation on this click before the rest of the form is displayed.

As far as i can gather from other questions on here my method should work.. `var validate` should equal `true` if errors are found which will stop the form progressing but will allow the form to progress once the fields have been filled and the button is clicked again

However all this seems to do at the moment is validate the very first field and then do nothing. Even if the field is valid it still will not progress with the rest of the actions on the function.

js library : http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js

method im trying to use: http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/

```
<div class="col-sm-8 sec-one">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="t1" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose an option...</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="D">D</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="t2" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose an option...</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="D">D</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="formbut next1">Next</button>
</div>


var validator = $("form").validate();

$(".next1").click(function () {
    validator.element('.sec-one [name]');
    if (validator) {
        $(".sec-one").slideUp("slow", function () {
            $(".sec-two").slideDown("slow");
        });


    } else {}
});
```

Comment: *"As far as i can gather from other questions on here my method should work.. `var validate` should equal `true` if errors are found"* ~ I'm not sure where you saw that.   Refer to [the official website](http://jqueryvalidation.org) and simply use the `.valid()` method to ***test*** the form.  `true` indicates **no** errors.  Otherwise, `$('#yourform').validate().element()` returns `true` if there are **no** errors.  In your code, you've dropped the `element()` part from your conditional.

Comment: @Sparky cheers for this.. could you post the correct way to do this as an answer then so I can give you credit? Be useful for other users too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "As far as i can gather from other questions on here my method should work.. `var validate` should equal `true` if errors are found"

[I'm not sure where you saw that](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/).  In your code, you've dropped the `element()` part from your conditional.   And `$('#yourform').validate().element()` is supposed to **return `true` if there are no errors**.

```
var validator = $("#myform").validate();  // create the validator variable
validator.element("#myselect"); // test an element
```

---

Better way...

Refer to the official website and simply use [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid) to test the form and/or individual elements. A `true` indicates **no errors**.

```
$('#myform').valid();
```

or

```
$('input[name="myelement"]').valid();
```